# SBS 2011 remote certificate issue

Tags: iis, windows-sbs-2011, outlook-web-app

Been trying at this for 2 days but still no joy.

I have an SSL Cert for my remote. sub-domain however when I bind it to the Default website on SBS 2011 I get nothing but autodiscover and other mismatch errors I cant afford a wildcard certificate. Is there anyway to move the OWA virtual directory in IIS to its own sub domain. for example owa.mydomain.com I can change my SSL cert to this if i can do this. nothing I do seems to resolve this issue just creates more.

any advice would be greatly received.

Comment: If you can't afford a wildcard cert, you can't really afford to be running a server, either.

Comment: Install the cert in error in the remote machine via gpo in worst case

Comment: @HopelessN00b by can't afford i meant didn't want to its a test server :D not going to pay 180 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the remote.*subdomain* to the Forward Lookup Zones in the DNS?